# How to convert a Website content to Mobile Application?With PhoneGap for windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, jquery-mobile, cordova, rss

I Have a Web site which has a huge data like log in,about us,RSS feed,status,search,results,submit your status,etc

So in that i want to use only some of contents like log in,RSS feed,search,submit your status in the part of mobile application so I want to use 50% of the Website in the part of Basic mobile application.

I want it for Windows Phone Only Using Phone Gap.. any one please help me regarding this even any example also no problem...

Actually I have URL there is No Server side Content is it Possible To do this kind in PhoneGap..

Comment: let me know if want more clariftication

Answer (score 1):

If your website not separate between client side language(html,css and javascript) and server side language (PHP, JSP), maybe it can't be done because phonegap only support client side language only. I suggest you separate your client side language and server side language. Convert your server side logic into web service so your app can request and response either in  XML or JSON data. You can use either RESTFUL or SOAP for your web service.

Comment: Yes @Dato' Mohammead Nurdin sir,  Insted of Using Restful services can i Use 50% of website as Mobile application i dont have any preferences from server side except RSS feed is it Possible with Phone GAP

Comment: As long your website not contain server side language. If yes, you need to convert it to web service.

Comment: no sir, actually there is a RSS content, so i successfully parsed that content in mobile But right now i need add a Login and Submit status which will directly communicate with real Login Details of that server. With out using Restful or JSON is it possible in Phone gap..

Comment: nope. it's impossible in phonegap. you need RESTFUL to make it works.